# Did Spring 4.03 vs 3.2.6 change how @Transactional works for Services

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

We've run in to an issue when upgrading to Spring 4 from 3. We've done some testing, but haven't come to a definitive conclusion yet. Basically what we're seeing is that our code which looks something like this isn't saving the newly created entity. This same code worked before upgrading to Spring 4. It seems basic enough that we must be missing something, but so far we haven't figured out why we now need to add the extra @Transactional.

```
@Transactional
SomeWebSerivce
{
  someAutowiredDomainService.doStuff();
}

@Service
SomeAutowiredDomainService
{
  doStuff(){
    Foo foo = getAttachedEntityFoo();
    foo.createChildEntityBarAndAttachToFooThroughOneToOneMapping(); //<-- this is not persisted to the DB, but if we mark SomeAutowiredDomainService with @Transactional everything works correctly.
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't recall any change in that area. It's really hard to figure out what your problem might be with your current description.

Comment: There have been some (minor?) changes in the hibernate integration not so much on the transaction stuff. Please add some configuration (hibernate/entitymanager) and the code of the `getAttachedEntityFoo` and `createChildEntityBarAndAttachToFooThroughOneToOneMapping` methods. The fact that your transaction isn't working makes me wonder if the `SomeWebService` is even properly configured/transactional at all.

Comment: @M.Deinum you are correct, the web services aren't actually being run in a transaction. When I call `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()` I get false back, so apparently we messed something up in the upgrade. Not sure what yet.

Comment: You might or might not have, next to that imho you shouldn't have your web service (or anything web or adapter related) transactional as the service is the proper tx layer. Make sure that the `<tx:annotation-driven />` is in the same location (some application context) as your web services, if they aren't they aren't transactional. Also beware component-scanning make sure you aren't scanning twice for the same components.

Comment: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11923